# $z^{41} = -7 + 41 i $, how many roots has $Im (z) >= 1/2$

Tags: complex-numbers

I got $z^{41} = -7 + 41 i $ and need find how many roots has $Im (z) >= 1/2$. I think i need find roots, that have in trigonometric form angle between angles, that have $sin(\alpha) = \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{(-7)^2+(41)^2}}$ (nearly between $0^{\circ} 41' 19"$ and $179^{\circ} 18' 41"$).
But i thing this method because of approximateness can't give me 100% right answer. Maybe You know another methods to solve it?
Big thanks, sorry for bad english.

Comment: As long as you can get the angles accurately a few decimals out, you should be fine.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you need to determine this?